# How to navigate through a list using iterators? (C++)

Tags: c++, iterator, listiterator

my code is

```
list<int> foo;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        foo.push_back(i);
    }
    for (std::list<int>::iterator it = foo.begin(); it != foo.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
```

I want my iterator increase in 3

and the output will be:

```
0 3 6 9 12 15 18
```

instead of:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Comment: use array instead of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list has a bidirectional iterator only (You can only increment or decrement the iterator via ++ or --). To advance the iterator by three you could std::advance(it, 3), but that might pass the end and lead to an infinite loop / undefined behavior.

Hence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> foo;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        foo.push_back(i);
    }
    std::list<int>::iterator it = foo.begin();
    while(it != foo.end()) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
        // Advance by three, stop at end
        for(int i = 0; i < 3 && it != foo.end(); ++i, ++it);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: You might choose a different container supporting random access (std::array, std::vector, std::deque) instead.

Answer (score 3):

In a list, you cannot advance the iterator by `n` instantly (e.g. `it+3`), because it is not a *random access iterator*. However, you can increment the iterator 3 times: `++(++(++it)))`.

As pointed out in the comment, you can use `std::advance(it,3)` but for the list iterator it will boil down to repeatedly calling `++it` 3 times.

Comment: you mean `std::advance(it,3)`?

Comment: `std::advance` hides the `++it` operation, but that is what happens under the hood (for the list iterator). However, the random access iterator has the `it+n` operator which works in O(1)

Comment: btw, assume, if it points to `size() - 1`, `++(++(++it)))` points to 2 elements after `end`

Comment: Multiple increment is undefined behavior only for fundamental types. Iterators have their ++ operator overloaded, defined as separate functions and UB does not occur (as mentioned in the comments to the answer of the question you linked)